# How to set sound from user ringtones in UILocalNotfication?

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I want 10 ringtones, and as I am setting my UILocalNotification, I want the particular ringtone should be rang?
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add these ringtones as sound files to your project and then assign appropriate sound based on user selection. According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can either specify the default sound using the constant or specify custom filename. No way to access iPhone's ringtones:

> soundName The name of the file containing the sound to play when an
> alert is displayed.
>
> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *soundName
>
> Discussion
>
> For this
> property, specify the filename (including extension) of a sound
> resource in the application’s main bundle or
> UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName to request the default system
> sound. When the system displays an alert for a local notification or
> badges an application icon, it plays this sound. The default value is
> nil (no sound). Sounds that last longer than 30 seconds are not
> supported. If you specify a file with a sound that plays over 30
> seconds, the default sound is played instead.